# Active routes navbar highlighting in Meteor

Tags: css, meteor, navigation, effects

I'm trying to highlight navbar items that are active as shown below on Medium.com. I have added the zimme:iron-router-active package but I still am not reaching my desired effect. What's the easiest way to accomplish the bold highlighting and the bar on the bottom when the item is pressed?

[image]

This is what I have so far:

```
 <div class="navSecondary">
        <div class="menu" align="center">
            <ul class="menu-items">
                <li class="{{ isActiveRoute home }}"><a href="{{pathFor 'home'}}"> HOME </a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
 </div>
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li class="{{isActiveRoute regex='home'}}"><a href="{{pathFor 'home'}}"> HOME </a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: What does the regex do exactly? I still can't see a highlighted HOME button when I click it.

Comment: it is just a keyword which gives you the possibility to do also regular expressions for you menuitems. Maybe you can post a bit more code or even better some sample project to validate.